# Is it possible to change data source in my script based on different categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Html.
I have auto-complete search bar(text box) along with 3 different option to filter search that is based on 1)Employee name 2) Employee ID 3) Email ID.
So based on the filter option selected data source(i mean list) should change.
Help me to change the data source in the script based on the option selected in dropdown

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="margin:15px 0px 0px 20px; cursor:pointer; width:180px!important">
                    <select class="form-control" id="searchFilterList" style="width:200px!important" onchange="changeSearchBarID()">
                        <option value="employeeName">Employee Name</option>
                        <option value="employeeID">Employee ID</option>
                        <option value="emailID">Email ID</option>
                    </select>

<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="EmployeeNameSearch"; style="max-width:800px!important;">
```

My Script. I have three list

```
<script>
                            $(function () {

                                var employeeNameList = [
                                    "Abishek Chandrasekar", "Bharat", "Deepak", "Eric",
                                        "Fizil", "Gowtham", "Harbajan",
                                        "Akshara", "Roshini"
                                ];

                                var employeeIDList = [
                                    "SF1010", "SF2010", "SF3010", "SF4010",
                                        "SF5010", "SF6010", "SF7010",
                                        "SF9010", "SF8010"
                                ];

                                var emaiIDList = [
                                    "abishek.chandrasekar@syncfusion.com", "bharath@syncfusion.com", "deepak@syncfusion.com", "eric@syncfusion.com",
                                        "fizil@syncfusion.com", "gowtham@syncfusion.com", "harbajan@syncfusion.com",
                                        "akshara@syncfusion.com", "roshini@syncfusion.com"
                                ];
                                $('#EmployeeNameSearch').ejAutocomplete({
                                    width: "800px",
                                    dataSource: employeeNameList /*I wanna change this list namebased on the selected category in dropdown*/
                                });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Destroy](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejautocomplete#methods:destroy) and reinitialize the plugin in the change event of your select:

You can try something like this:

```
   data =  {
  employeeName: [
    "Abishek Chandrasekar", "Bharat", "Deepak", "Eric",
    "Fizil", "Gowtham", "Harbajan",
    "Akshara", "Roshini"
  ],
  employeeID: [
    "SF1010", "SF2010", "SF3010", "SF4010",
    "SF5010", "SF6010", "SF7010",
    "SF9010", "SF8010"
  ],
  emaiID: [
    "abishek.chandrasekar@syncfusion.com", "bharath@syncfusion.com", "deepak@syncfusion.com", "eric@syncfusion.com",
    "fizil@syncfusion.com", "gowtham@syncfusion.com", "harbajan@syncfusion.com",
    "akshara@syncfusion.com", "roshini@syncfusion.com"
  ]
};

    $('#searchFilterList').change(function(){
     name = $(this).val();
     $('#EmployeeNameSearch').ejAutocomplete("destroy");
     $('#EmployeeNameSearch').ejAutocomplete({
        width: "800px",
        dataSource: data[name]
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should listen on the `change` event of the Select box using jQuery's `on` event handler. When the value of select box changes, the relevant data is chosen based on the selected option, and then the autocomplete box is re-initialized with the right data.

```
(function () {
    var employeeNameList = [
        "Abishek Chandrasekar", "Bharat", "Deepak", "Eric",
        "Fizil", "Gowtham", "Harbajan",
        "Akshara", "Roshini"
    ];

    var employeeIDList = [
        "SF1010", "SF2010", "SF3010", "SF4010",
        "SF5010", "SF6010", "SF7010",
        "SF9010", "SF8010"
    ];

    var emaiIDList = [
        "abishek.chandrasekar@syncfusion.com", "bharath@syncfusion.com", "deepak@syncfusion.com", "eric@syncfusion.com",
        "fizil@syncfusion.com", "gowtham@syncfusion.com", "harbajan@syncfusion.com",
        "akshara@syncfusion.com", "roshini@syncfusion.com"
    ];

    function initAutocomplete(data) {
        $('#EmployeeNameSearch').ejAutocomplete("destroy");
        $('#EmployeeNameSearch').ejAutocomplete({
            width: "800px",
            dataSource: data
        });
    }

    // when filter box value is changed, re-init
    // autocomplete based on selected option
    $('#searchFilterList').on('change', function () {
        var selectedOption = $(this).val();

        if (selectedOption === 'employeeName') {
            initAutocomplete(employeeNameList);
        } else if (selectedOption === 'employeeID') {
            initAutocomplete(employeeIDList);
        } else if (selectedOption === 'emailID') {
            initAutocomplete(emaiIDList);
        } else {
            initAutocomplete([]);
        }
    });

    // On page load, initialize autocomplete with employee names
    initAutocomplete(employeeNameList);
})();
```